# Use case for /render endpoints?

Tags: support, api-v2.2

In the new v2.2 API there are /render endpoints, such as `/questions/{id}/answers/render`. What are these for? Testing applications without actually posting anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can use these endpoints to provide a user with preview functionality, since you can get back the submitted content as Stack Exchange would render it without the user having to actually create something in the system.

I assume this is the primary use case.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be simpler to render the markdown locally?

Comment: Not necessarily, the SE Markdown engine has various modifications/extensions that might make delegating the rendering the more reliable solution.